# Batch edit Alt Text

Tags: product, magento2.3, product-images, text

I want to update the Alt Text for each of my 14,000 products to match them with the Product Name. Is there a script I can use or an option I can select to edit them all at once? How long will it take?

Comment: you can create your own sql query

Comment: Could you give me a template or suggestion for the query? I am still new to SQL and don't know how to reference Alt Text and Product Name as database entries @CharanjeetSingh